# Make one line command from shell scripts

Tags: shell

I'm trying to execute scripts body as a command on a remote target.

Can someone help me to make the following scripts as one line command?

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
cd /target/path 
FILES=`find -type f -name '*.*'`
for f in $FILES
do
perl -i.tokens -pe '
    s[ ( \{\{ (.+?) \}\} ) ]
     [
        if (exists $ENV{$2}) {
            $ENV{$2}
        } else {
            warn "unknown component property $2 in file $ARGV\n";
            $1
        }
     ]gex
' $f
done
```

Thanks in advance,
Andriy

Comment: why do you want to? You already have the functionality in one place, and your command line to invoke it is already very short.

Comment: Previously it was script that was executed on the remote target. Due to changed permission, this required to be executed as command inside another script.

Comment: By the way, you're reading filenames unsafely. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 0):

You can condense it to:

```
find /target/path -name '*.*' -type f -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i.tokens -pe 's/(\{\{(.+?)\}\})/exists $ENV{$2} ? $ENV{$2} : do {warn "unknown ..."; $1}/ge'
```

Assumes you have GNU tools.